# Is there any evidence of modern technology today that has been rediscovered?

Tags: technology

Is there any evidence of modern technology or high population today that has been rediscovered?
The earth has frozen over multiple times surely there is an example like this.

For example

- computer like technology
- cars
- high billion population

Comment: I have been reading your question for several minutes and I am still wondering about the supposed logic of your premise. How would the fact that the Earth had "frozen over[sic]" support the idea of the existence of a previous civilization? In any case, the [Homo Sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens) is relatively recent and the glacial periods it has supported are very far from being "The earth has frozen over" (hint: if the Earth had frozen the Homo Sapiens would not have survived).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: There are examples in the answers to this closed question: [Are there any examples of technologies have been lost over time?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/53838/are-there-any-examples-of-technologies-have-been-lost-over-time/53841#53841).

Comment: @SJuan76 hmm there are many mysteries like the Bermuda triangle, the pyramids, and stone hedge.  I had considered maybe somebody brought only certain people into the next future and the world would go dark.  Think maybe of an Atlantis scenario or much worse time travel.

Comment: @William I think you would find answers more suitable to what you're looking for at SE Esotericism. :p

Answer (score 3):

> **Question:**.
>   Is there any evidence of modern technology or high population today that has been rediscovered?

Not due to ice age but certainly due to wars and the fall of civilizations.

The **[antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism)**, found inside a Roman shipwreck near the Greek island of Antikythera, was an ancient mechanical computer thought to be at least 2,000 years old. It's believed that this complex clock-like device was used by ancient Greeks to calculate the movement of the stars and planets.

**[Roman Concrete](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/07/why-modern-mortar-crumbles-roman-concrete-lasts-millennia)**  Europe lost the ability to make concrete altogether after the fall of Rome and even up til the end of the 20th century modern concrete lacked the durability of concrete which the Romans used.   Have you ever seen old cracked concrete?  Roman Concrete has lasted two millennium. Some Roman Concrete that old was used for underwater construction.  20th century concrete could never stand up to that kind of use.  It wasn’t until relatively recently that we figured out the formula which the Romans used to make such durable concrete structures.

**[Byzantine Greek fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire)**.  An early chemical or pyrotechnic weapon.  Modern scientists still don’t know how to make that.

**[Universal antidote](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128153390000111)** said to cure all poisons developed by King Mithridates VI of Pontus (who reigned 120–63 B.C.) and perfected by Emperor Nero’s personal physician.

**[Damascus Steel](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226009451_Discovery_of_Nanotubes_in_Ancient_Damascus_Steel)**  incredible strong durable steel made famous during the medieval times,  modern steel workers could not reproduce the technique until the 21st century when electron microscopes were used to reveal quantum structures like “cementite nanowires and carbon nanotubes.” In the medieval steel.

**Mongol Bow**. Technology still lost to the modern age.  We know roughly how they were made but not the specific techniques used to manufacture and tune them.  Modern attempts to recreate this super weapon of its time fail to produce the same range and are based upon a rival archery tradition.

> **[Mongol Bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_bow)**
>    The Mongol bowmaking tradition was lost under the Manchus, who forbade archery; the present bowmaking tradition emerged after independence in 1921 and is based on Manchu types of bow.[44] Mounted archery had fallen into disuse and has been revived only in the 21st century.

**Sources:**

- **[Why Modern Mortar Crumbles and Roman Concrete Lasts Millennia](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/07/why-modern-mortar-crumbles-roman-concrete-lasts-millennia)**
- **[Composite Bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_bow)**
- **Physics and Engineering of New Materials [Damascus Steel](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226009451_Discovery_of_Nanotubes_in_Ancient_Damascus_Steel)**
- **[Universal antidote](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128153390000111)**
- **[antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism)**

Comment: What about the great pyramids?  Is it really feasible for them to exist in the way they did?

Comment: @William, yes. It just takes many workers.

Comment: @William,   I considered both the Great Pyramids and the Incan city of Machu Pichu,  but I wasn't entirely sure they fit.   Thought I would leave those examples to someone who knew more about them.